# Auto Refresh Flask Based when DB Changes

Tags: python, database, flask

So I have a bit of data in the db that needs to be displayed as tables. I want the table to refresh whenever data is changed in the db. or maybe even get new data from the db maybe every 20 seconds.

The data is pushed to the db via another py file and that keeps it updated every 20 seconds or so. so every 20 seconds I want flask to grab the new data.
My code.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)

Bootstrap(app)

db_name = 'databases/nez.db'

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + db_name

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Nez(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'nez'
    index = db.Column(db.Integer)
    time = db.Column(db.String)
    pair = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    profit = db.Column(db.Float)
    bid = db.Column(db.Float)
    ask = db.Column(db.Float)
    volume = db.Column(db.String)
    latency = db.Column(db.String)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/nez')
def nezs():
    nez = Nez.query.all()
    return render_template('list.html', nez=nez)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I added this code on the top of my template

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20" />
where 20 is 20 seconds.

It refreshes the whole page. I want it to only refresh the table.

Comment: This is more of a client side task. In any case, you need to write a javascript code that will receive data from the server and update the table.